# MixItUp with dropdown filter with AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, mixitup

I'm trying to use MixItUp with AngularJS which works ok with buttons, but when trying to use it with dropdown it doesn't.

```
<select class="filter" ng-model="selectedCategory"
        ng-options="'.' + cat.id as cat.name for cat in categories track by cat.id">
    <option value="">-- Category --</option>
</select>
<pre>{{ selectedCategory }}</pre>

<div mix-it-up class="container">
    <div class="mix {{widget.categoryId}}" data-myorder="{{widget.name}}" 
         ng-repeat="widget in widgets">
                  {{widget.name}}
    </div>
    <div class="gap"></div>
    <div class="gap"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dp31o591/2/

Answer (score 0):

I figure this one out. Just have to use the event on change:

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="category" ng-change="filterCategory(category)"
ng-options="'.cat' + cat.id as cat.name for cat in categories track by cat.id">
      <option value="" ng-model="category" 
              ng-change="filterCategory(category)">All</option>
           </select>
```

and the controller:

```
$scope.filterCategory = function (cat) {
    cat = cat === null ? 'all' : cat
    $('#sandbox').mixItUp('filter', cat);
};
```

And that's the working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dp31o591/3/